# Centered logo with varied widths and multiple lists

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to create a navigation bar which consists of three pieces, a list to the left of the centered logo, the logo itself and a list to the right of the logo. I've tried absolutely positioning the logo and floating the lists however this leads to the logo overlaying the lists when the width of the browser is altered.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, JSFiddle included below :-).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B29y5/2/)

**HTML**

```
 <div class="navigation">
    <div class="container-1020">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
            <div class="nav-logo">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x60"/>
            </div>
        <ul>
            <li>01234 123456</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navigation {
    background: #222222;
}

.container-1020 {
    max-width: 1020px;
    min-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    display: inline; 
    margin-right: 10px;
}

li:last-child {
     margin-right: 0 !important;   
}

.logo-container {
     width: 200px;
     height: 60px;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you
[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4t5Mm/)
css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navigation {
    background: #222222;
}
.container-1020 {
    max-width: 1020px;
    min-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul {
    color: #fff;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
}
ul:last-child {
    text-align: right;
}
.nav-logo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="container-1020">
        <ul class="left">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="nav-logo">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x60" />
        </div>
        <ul class="right">
            <li>01234 123456</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

well for one, correct your class name for the logo, is it `.nav-logo` or `.logo-container`

then set your ul's and whichever logo container class you decide on to `display:inline-block`

Comment: That's my error, I didn't copy and paste the CSS directly from the document I'm using.